# Transpilation into custom gate set in qiskit

Tags: programming, qiskit, gate-synthesis, compiling, transpile

In `qiskit`, I can transpile a given circuit into a some predefined gate set as follows (just an example)

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.compiler import transpile
from qiskit.circuit.random import random_circuit

basis_gates = ['id', 'u3', 'cx']

qc = random_circuit(3, 1, seed=0)
qc_trans = transpile(qc, basis_gates=basis_gates)
```

I have several related questions.

1. Where can I find an exhaustive list of operators allowed as `basis_gates`?
2. For any operator label from the list of allowed basis gates, how can I find the precise meaning of the corresponding gate, say as a matrix representation?
3. Most importantly, can I add my own custom gates to use as basis gates? Can I add parametric gates? For examples as far as I can tell `qiskit` standard tools include `Rxz` and `Ryz` gates but no `Rxy` gate. Can I make one?

---

Example of a (trivial) transpilation into custom gate set failing

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.compiler import transpile

qc = QuantumCircuit(2, name='mycx')
qc.cx(0, 1)
mycx = qc.to_gate()
qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.cx(0, 1)

transpile(qc, basis_gates=['id','mycx'])
```

gives me a `TranspileError`.

Comment: in your `mycx` example, you probably mean `qc.append(mycx, [0, 1])` instead of `qc.cx(0, 1)`. With that change, it works.

Comment: @luciano Nono, the whole point is that although `cx` is essential the same as `mycx` I would like the transpiler to find that out. More generally, I would like to get the transpilation into any custom universal gate set.

Comment: I added the section *Your custom gate as basis target of a circuit that is not using it* as part of my answer. Let me know if that makes it.

Comment: Also, check this youtube video: [Unitary matrix to 1Q, 2QGates](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O2WcZS4yO1Q)

Answer (score 12):

#### The Qiskit standard gate list

You can find the full list of Qiskit standard gates in the module `qiskit.circuit.library.standard_gates` ([documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/circuit_library.html#standard-gates)).

#### The matrix representation of a standard gate

For each gate, you can see its matrix representation with the `to_matrix` method. For example:

```
from qiskit.circuit.library import standard_gates
standard_gates.HGate().to_matrix()
```

```
array([[ 0.70710678+0.j,  0.70710678+0.j],
       [ 0.70710678+0.j, -0.70710678+0.j]])
```

Or, its latex representation:

```
from qiskit.visualization import array_to_latex
array_to_latex(standard_gates.HGate().to_matrix())
```

[image: matrix output in latex]

#### Creating your own custom gate

You can create your own gates from a circuit. For example:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

custom_circuit = QuantumCircuit(2, name='bell')
custom_circuit.h(0)
custom_circuit.cx(0, 1)

custom_gate = custom_circuit.to_gate()
```

You can create a circuit using that custom gate:

```
circuit = QuantumCircuit(3)
circuit.h(0)
circuit.append(custom_gate, [0,1])
circuit.cx(1, 2)
circuit.draw()
```

```
     ┌───┐┌───────┐     
q_0: ┤ H ├┤0      ├─────
     └───┘│  bell │     
q_1: ─────┤1      ├──■──
          └───────┘┌─┴─┐
q_2: ──────────────┤ X ├
                   └───┘
```

#### Telling the transpiler not to decompose your custom gate

Following the previous example, you can transpile that circuit using the custom gate name in the target basis list:

```
from qiskit.compiler import transpile

basis_gates = ['bell', 'u3', 'cx']

qc_trans = transpile(circuit, basis_gates=basis_gates)
qc_trans.draw()
```

```
     ┌─────────────┐┌───────┐     
q_0: ┤ U3(π/2,0,π) ├┤0      ├─────
     └─────────────┘│  bell │     
q_1: ───────────────┤1      ├──■──
                    └───────┘┌─┴─┐
q_2: ────────────────────────┤ X ├
                             └───┘
```

#### Your custom gate as basis target of a circuit that is not using it

You can basis-target your own custom in some cases. That requires to extend the *equivalence library*. Following your `mycx` example:

1. Create a circuit definition with your custom gate

```
mycx = QuantumCircuit(2, name='mycx')
mycx.cx(0, 1)

mycx_def = QuantumCircuit(2)
mycx_def.append(mycx.to_gate(), [0, 1])
```

2. Add an equivalence to the library where a gate (`CXGate` in this case) is equivalent to that definition.

```
StandardEquivalenceLibrary.add_equivalence(CXGate(), mycx_def)
```

3. Create a circuit that uses the domain gate (`CXGate` in this case).

```
from qiskit.compiler import transpile

qc = QuantumCircuit(3)
qc.h(0)
qc.cx(0, 1)
qc.cx(1, 2)
```

4. Transpile using the parameter `translation_method='translator'`. This will tell the transpiler to use the equivalence library for basis translation. In the `basis_gate` parameter you can refer to your custom gate name (`mycx` in this case):

```
result = transpile(qc, basis_gates=['mycx', 'u3'], translation_method='translator')
result.draw()
```

```
     ┌─────────────┐┌───────┐         
q_0: ┤ U3(π/2,0,π) ├┤0      ├─────────
     └─────────────┘│  mycx │┌───────┐
q_1: ───────────────┤1      ├┤0      ├
                    └───────┘│  mycx │
q_2: ────────────────────────┤1      ├
                             └───────┘
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer! I have several follow up questions though. 

(1) If I just have a label from `basis_gates` list like `'u3'` or `'cx'`, can I do something like `Gate.from_label('cx')` instead of looking up the documentation to get the gate?

Comment: (2) Your example of transpilation is a bit trivial because you use the custom 'bell' gate both in the original circuit and in the transpiled circuit. In a more practical situation the transpilation seems to fail. Please see updated question.

Comment: It is not possible to make a `from_label`. But it looks like a great feature request candidate: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/new?type%3A+feature+request&template=FEATURE_REQUEST.md

Comment: Your `mycx` example fails because `qc` includes `cx` which is not in the basis. (and you probably forgot to append `mycx` to `qc`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for further elaboration! Still, it seems that we have different goals in mind. Ideally, I would like to transpile an arbitrary circuit into *any* custom gate set which is universal. Theorems like Solovay-Kitaev's guarantee that this is possible. Perhaps I am interested whether there is some general-purpose algorithm under the hood in qiskit that does that. From your new amendment I gather that I need to set the rules for decomposing into my custom gate set by hands. So I would guess that current qiskit traspiler can only target gates native to IBM machines?

Comment: Kinda. Qiskit is/pretends-to-be hardware agnostic. Qiskit handle qiskit standard gates in the equivalence library. If your universal basis set is not in the standard gate set, you need to create it with custom gates and add the equivalences to the library.

Comment: Another possibility is to synthesis to your basis from some low-level representation. If so, you could write transpilation passes that take you that representation and then run that synthesis. For example, we have way to go to clifford+t, if you can convert that to your basis, then it is _just_ that last step missing.

Comment: For custom single qubit circuit, I am getting error `CircuitError: "to_matrix not defined for this <class 'qiskit.circuit.gate.Gate'>"` for `array_to_latex(custom_circuit.to_gate().to_matrix())`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use BQSKit to accomplish this very easily. BQSKit is a powerful and portable quantum compiler/transpiler. You will need to calculate the unitary of your gate and you can just plug that into BQSKit.

You can accomplish this with the following:

```
from bqskit import compile, MachineModel, Circuit
from bqskit.ir.gates import IdentityGate, ConstantUnitaryGate
mycx = ConstantUnitaryGate([...]) # Fill in unitary here
model = MachineModel(gate_set={mycx, IdentityGate(1)})
output_circuit = compile(circuit, model)
```