# How to implement parametric iSWAP gate in Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-gate

I'm trying to implement the parametric $\text{iSWAP}$ gate, also known as $\text{XY}(\theta)$, in Qiskit.

$$
\text{XY}(\theta)=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos{\theta/2} & i\sin{\theta/2} & 0 \\
0 & i\sin{\theta/2} & \cos{\theta/2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Furthermore, once I've implemented this gate I would like to use it in order to decompose quantum circuits in terms of single-qubit gates and $\text{XY}(\theta)$ as the only two-qubit gate.

What are the steps that I need to do in order to achieve this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**
Qiskit 0.35 introduced a new gate [`XXPlusYYGate`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.XXPlusYYGate.html).

$$\newcommand{\th}{\frac{\theta}{2}}\\\begin{split}R_{XX+YY}(\theta, \beta)\ q_0, q_1 =
    \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0                     & 0                    & 0  \\
        0 & \cos(\th)             & i\sin(\th)e^{i\beta} & 0  \\
        0 & i\sin(\th)e^{-i\beta} & \cos(\th)            & 0  \\
        0 & 0                     & 0                    & 1
    \end{pmatrix}\end{split}$$
So, you can now add parameterized $\text{XY}$ to your circuit as follows:

```
theta = Parameter('θ')
circ.append(XXPlusYYGate(theta, 0), [0, 1])
```

---

**Original Answer**

For the first part of your question, we have
$$XY(\theta) = \exp(-i {\frac{\theta}{2}} (X{\otimes}X + Y{\otimes}Y))$$
And since $X{\otimes}X$ and $Y{\otimes}Y$ commute, we can write it as
$$XY(\theta) = \exp(-i {\frac{\theta}{2}} X{\otimes}X) \exp(-i {\frac{\theta}{2}} Y{\otimes}Y)$$
Qiskit already has these two gates:
$$R_{XX}(\theta) = \exp(-i {\frac{\theta}{2}} X{\otimes}X)$$
And,
$$R_{YY}(\theta) = \exp(-i {\frac{\theta}{2}} Y{\otimes}Y)$$

Hence, the implementation of $XY(\theta)$ as a parameterized gate in Qiskit will be as simple as

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit import Parameter

theta = Parameter('θ')

circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.rxx(theta, 0, 1)
circuit.ryy(theta, 0, 1)
param_iswap = circuit.to_gate()
```

---

**Another Solution**

If you want to use more basic gates than `rxx` and `ryy`, you can use Qiskit's Operator Flow:

```
H = 0.5 * ((X^X) + (Y^Y))
theta = Parameter('θ')
evolution_op = (theta * H).exp_i() # exp(-iθH)

trotterized_op = PauliTrotterEvolution(trotter_mode = Suzuki(order = 1, reps = 1)).convert(evolution_op)
circuit = trotterized_op.to_circuit()
circuit.draw('mpl')
```

The composition:
[image]
And as before

```
param_iswap = circuit.to_gate()
```

For the second part of your question, I think the best answer you can have is the [one](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/17861/9474) mentioned in the comments by @epelaaez, as it is recent and from a member of Qiskit's development team.

Answer (score 4):

You can implement an arbitrary unitary matrix as a [Unitary Gate](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.extensions.UnitaryGate.html#qiskit.extensions.UnitaryGate.__init__) using the `UnitaryGate` class that qiskit provides. This class can be instantiated with an `np.ndarray` containing the definition of your *valid* unitary gate and a name for that unitary.
It would look something like -

```
from qiskit.extensions import UnitaryGate
def U_theta(theta):
    arr = np.array([[1,0,0,0],
                    [0,np.cos(theta/2), 1j*np.sin(theta/2), 0],
                    [0,1j*np.sin(theta/2),np.cos(theta/2),0],
                    [0,0,0,1]])
    u_gate = UnitaryGate(data = arr,label = 'iSwap'+str(theta))
    return u_gate

gate1 = U_theta(0.5) # would return a gate with theta = 0.5
```

This gate can be used in your quantum circuits and attached to the relevant qubits using the `compose` function.

Regarding transpilation, I am not sure if qiskit allows us to give a *custom* basis set for transpilation but you could always keep a pre-transpiled version of your $iSWAP$ gate and just attach it to your current circuit.

Hope it helps!

Comment: [This](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/17861/16092) answer might helpl with the custom transpilation.