# When I try to transpile circuit with Qiskit, how can I use $Ry(\pi/2)$ as a basis gate?

Tags: qiskit, programming

When I try to transpile circuit with Qiskit, I can use `'ry'` as a basis gate. But I want to set one of the basis gate as $R_y(\pi/2)$. How can I do that?

Edited:

```
my_z2 = QuantumCircuit(1,name='z2')
my_z2.rz(np.pi,0)
z2_def = QuantumCircuit(1)
z2_def.append(my_z2.to_gate(),[0])
StandardEquivalenceLibrary.add_equivalence(RZGate(np.pi), z2_def)

qc = QuantumCircuit(1)
qc.rz(np.pi,0)
qc_trans = transpile(qc, basis_gates=['id','z2'],translation_method='translator')
qc_trans.draw('mpl')
```

This is my code and it throws CircuitError:
`CircuitError: 'Cannot bind parameters (rz[0]) not present in the circuit.'`

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can define $R_y(\pi/2)$ as a custom gate, then follow the method described here: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/17861/9474

Comment: Thanks. But I cannot find the code corresponds to **StandardEquivalenceLibrary.add_equivalence(CXGate(), mycx_def)**. StandardEquivalenceLibrary seems not exist.

Comment: from qiskit.circuit.library.standard_gates.equivalence_library import StandardEquivalenceLibrary

Comment: I follow the steps but it raise a circuit error.

Comment: @Inm do you need to just transpile to a circuit with that basis, or then actually compile it to be executed on a machine?